# Displaying only desired columns in a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

In my grid(Telerik's RadGrid) i'm giving as datasource what a LINQ method returns(list of objects).

```
GridDetails.DataSource = DAODetails_Prix.GetMontantDevisAcceptes_Details_Prix(annee, mois);
```

And:

```
    public static List<Details_Prix> GetMontantDevisAcceptes_Details_Prix(int annee,int month)
    {
        DataClassesActilogDataContext db = ContextSingleton.GetDataContext();
        List<Details_Prix> liste;

        var v = from i in db.Details_Prix
                where (i.dtDevisFact.Value.Month==month &&  i.dtDevisFact.Value.Year==annee &&i.DevisAccept==true)
                select i;

        liste = v.ToList();

        return liste;
    }
```

My problem is i don't want all the fields of the object to be displayed. i just need some of them in my grid.
How should i do?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In telerik Rad Grid

```
  protected void RadGrid1_ColumnCreated(object sender, Telerik.WebControls.GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
  {
       if (e.Column.UniqueName == "ColumnName")
       {
           e.Column.Visible = false;
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it like below after binding . if you dont want to go for ColumnCreated event.

```
GridDetails.DataSource = DAODetails_Prix.GetMontantDevisAcceptes_Details_Prix(annee, mois);
GridDetails.DataBind()

// hide columns which is not required
 GridDetails.MasterTableView.GetColumn("ColumnName").Visible = False
```